# Which preposition should I use with "purpose"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

The primordial purpose __________ schooling is ultimately to learn how to learn.

A. In

B. For

C. Of

D. At

Comment: @user178049: Answers do not belong in comments; they belong in answers, where they can be voted on.

Comment: Have you looked up purpose in a good online dictionary? That would give you a reasonable indication what pronouns fit with **purpose**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let alone the *premoridal* first and consider the important part

> purpose ___ schooling.

The typical noun phrase construction is `dependent+head`. In this context, schooling functions as the dependent modifing the head, *purpose*. So it should be,

> Schooling purpose

However, you can use the *of-pattern* as an alternative

> Purpose of schooling

**EDIT** : Okay, I had to agree with a native speaker. As @Andrew stated in the comment section, using *schooling* as a pre-head modifier is not idiomatic. The *of-pattern* is still a better option.

Comment: "The primordial schooling purpose"?  While I understand what you mean, I strongly disagree that this "should" be the answer.  Given that already the use of "primordial" is awkward in this context, if forced to adopt this syntax I much prefer "the primordial purpose **of** schooling".

Comment: @Andrew What I meant was *schooling purpose* would be a better option if there was no *primordial*. That's I ignore it(I stated it in the first paragraph).

Comment: "The schooling purpose" is still unidiomatic. As is "Schooling purpose" without the definite article.